# What exactly is the exclamation mark *in terms of the latex language* in the resizebox{width}{!}{object} command?

Tags: resize

More often than not, when I use the `\resizebox{width}{height}{object}` command it ends up looking something like this:

```
\resizebox{1\linewidth}{!}{%
  object
}%
```

I know from places like [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#Resize_tables) that the exclamation mark essentially automatically calculates the appropriate hight so as to retain the same aspect ratio as before.

What I don't know, is this something to do with tex / latex the language in general? Or is it simply syntax specific to the `resizebox` command? Does the exclamation mark in `\begin{figure}[!htbp]` have anything to do with that, or is this also simply syntax specific to the internals of the `{figure}` environment?

In other words, the question is, is the exclamation mark a language construct, and if so what is it, and what might be useful to know about it?
And if it's not a language construct and is simply syntax specific to certain functions, is there at least some sort of convention as to its meaning that might be useful to know?

Comment: When weird syntax is encountered, remember that TeX programs (I.e., classes, packages, and documents) can modify their own syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the definition of `\resizebox` in `graphics.sty` (line numbers added for reference):

```
244 \def\Gin@exclamation{!}

417 \def\resizebox{%
418   \leavevmode
419   \@ifstar{\Gscale@@box\totalheight}{\Gscale@@box\height}}
420 \def\Gscale@@box#1#2#3{%
421   \let\@tempa\Gin@exclamation
422   \expandafter\def\expandafter\@tempb\expandafter{\string#2}%
423   \expandafter\def\expandafter\@tempc\expandafter{\string#3}%
424   \ifx\@tempb\@tempa
425     \ifx\@tempc\@tempa
426       \toks@{\mbox}%
427     \else
428       \toks@{\Gscale@box@dd{#3}#1}%
429     \fi
430   \else
431     \ifx\@tempc\@tempa
432       \toks@{\Gscale@box@dd{#2}\width}%
433     \else
434       \toks@{\Gscale@box@dddd{#2}\width{#3}#1}%
435     \fi
436   \fi
437   \the\toks@}
```

The `*`-version uses `\totalheight` instead of `\height` and control is passed to `\Gscale@@box`, which absorbs the two arguments that appear as the arguments to `\resizebox`. The `\string` token in lines 422 and 423 is used because `babel` might have made `!` into an active character.

The three conditional compare the arguments to `\resizebox` with a normal `!`; if it is found, then the appropriate action is performed.

There's no special meaning for `!` in LaTeX or in the general TeX syntax; the developers of LaTeX just chose a character that is not supposed to belong in a dimension setting.

The case of `!` in the optional argument to a float environment is similar: just the choice of an easy character, well distinguishable from the other characters with a meaning in that argument.